# Data structure which is good in insertion, removal and random access

Tags: java, performance, data-structures

Currently, I am looking the following data structure.

1. Fast to insert at tail.
2. Fast to remove from head.
3. Able to perform random access.

I realize `ArrayBlockingQueue` is good at (1) and (2), and `ArrayList` is good at (3). Is there single data structure from standard library/ Apache libraries/ Google libraries, which enable me to have all 3 requirements at once?

Comment: May i know the reason behind using ArrayBlockingQueue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best datastructure for your case is a [ringbuffer/circular buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer). The ringbuffer performs all three operations in constant time.

An implementation can be found [here](http://www.keithschwarz.com/interesting/code/ring-buffer/RingBuffer.java.html) and many others [here](http://www.google.com/search?q=java+ringbuffer)

**edit:** the problem with ringbuffers is that you should know at the beginning how many elements are in that buffer in worst-case. But there also exist dynamic ringbuffers.

Comment: I think circular buffers are the data structure you want. A dynamic buffer can give you O(1) amortized insertion, in the same way as `ArrayList`, and also O(1) deletion (by moving the pointers). I don't know if it's implemented in the usual Java libraries.

Comment: +1. This exactly what the OP is looking for. I don't think there is one implemented in `java.util`, but it is easy enough to write one using an array.

Answer (score 0):

LinkedList may be suitable, if speed is not important for 3.  Note that ArrayBlockingQueue is designed for environments where multiple threads will access the List.  ArrayList and LinkedList are not.  You'd have to wrap them using `Collections.synchronizedList()` if you need to access them from multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

[LinkedHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) is the one u need to try.It gives u best of all.

Combination of Hash and Double LinkedList datastructure.